# Little help with a residue integration with branch point

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> $$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(4x^2+1)(x+1)}$$

Now I transformed it into

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{z\ dz}{z(4z^2+1)(z+1)}$$

To obtain the form

$$\frac{z^{\alpha}F(z)}{G(z)}$$

In such a wa I can apply residue calculus to get the answer as

$$\frac{2\pi i}{1 - e^{2\pi i \alpha}}\text{Res}[f, z]$$

Where a sum of residues is understood.

The poles are at $z = 0, -1, \pm \frac{1}{2}i$

The result shall be $\frac{2\pi }{5}$ but now the question is: how to deal with the poles at $\pm \frac{1}{2}i$? I would have a cumbersome square root of an imaginary unit.

Is there some "nicer" or smart way to deal with the integral?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x=u^2$ therefore$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(4x^2+1)(x+1)}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2du}{(4u^4+1)(u^2+1)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{du}{(4u^4+1)(u^2+1)}$$using the same famous contour for complex integration we have:$$\int_{C} \frac{dz}{(4z^4+1)(z^2+1)}=\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{du}{(4u^4+1)(u^2+1)}+\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{iRe^{i\theta}d\theta}{(4R^4e^{4i\theta}+1)(R^2e^{2i\theta}+1)}$$also $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{(4z^4+1)(z^2+1)}$ has 6 roots among those 3 contained by the contour and all are of order 1. Those 3 are:$$r_1=i\\r_2=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}e^{i\dfrac{\pi}{4}}\\r_3=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}e^{i\dfrac{3\pi}{4}}$$if we denote the residue of $f(z)$ in these points by $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$ we have:$$R_1=R_2+R_3=\dfrac{1}{10i}$$therefore$$R_1+R_2+R_3=\dfrac{1}{5i}$$and the integral would be$$\int_{C} \frac{dz}{(4z^4+1)(z^2+1)}=2\pi i(R_1+R_2+R_3)=\frac{2\pi}{5}$$which leads to $$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{du}{(4u^4+1)(u^2+1)}=\frac{2\pi}{5}$$

Comment: There is some problem. The result the professor said to be is $\frac{2\pi}{5}$. You got $\pi$ and Mathematica confirms the professor's result.

Comment: Let me check it out...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! It was a flaw in calculating residue........

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a great lesson to me1

Comment: That's very kind of you! Not at all........

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed set $x=u^2$ as Mostafa Ayaz did. However sooner or later you need to know how to deal with $\sqrt[\alpha]{z}$ with $z\in\mathbb{C}$ which is not even that difficult. From your words I understand that you were using the keyhole contour. The pole at zero was not inside the contour. So you actually had $z=1$, $\pm \frac{1}{2}i$ as simple poles inside your contour.

Moreover you have two kinds of pathes that look like circles, the large "circle" which will have no contribution as the radius goes to infinity, and the small "circle" which will have no contribution as well as the radius of it goes to zero. Check these, please!

Assuming you were using the Principal Logarithm to define the square root, I'll show you how to do the residue at $\frac{1}{2}i$:
\begin{align}
\text{Res}_{z=i/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{z}(4z^2+1)(z+1)}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt[]{i/2}(i/2+i/2)(i/2+1)}
\end{align} 
The only problematic thing here is the square root right? 
\begin{align}
\sqrt[]{i/2}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\text{Log}(i/2)}
\end{align}
That is how we defined it (I think you too? Since that is the standard way). 
\begin{align}
\text{Log}(i/2)=\ln|i/2| +i\text{Arg}(i/2)=-\ln(2)+i\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align} 
So:
\begin{align}
\sqrt[]{i/2}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(-\ln(2)+i\frac{\pi}{2} \right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2}}e^{i\pi/4}
\end{align}
I hope this was helpful.

Comment: +1 for your help, which is, generally, never enough. Everyone of us has something to add/teach to others, and your answer added details! Thank you.